# Not getting result in NSURLSession in swift

Tags: swift2, nsurlsession

In using swift 2.2, while using NSURLSession I am not getting the Response. What am I doing wrong?

I have to pass parameters and header in POST request.

```
func API() {

    let userName:String! = "uname"
    let password:String! = "password"

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: URL)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let data = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameter, options:[])
    let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
    request.HTTPBody = json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["key":"value"]

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume()

}
```

Result is:

> responseString = Optional("")

Comment: If you are going to send JSON you have to set the header accordingly.

Comment: I have updated the code, tried to send the header but it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

Did you call this service on any REST client like Postman ? if yes and get response so try replace this line

```
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["key":"value"]
```

with this

```
request.setValue("value",forHTTPHeaderField:"Key")
```

and set all values

Comment: Yes, I am getting result from postman. And I tried replacing what you wrote, unfortunately still not getting any response.

Comment: what language use as backend>

Comment: if you use postman you can find button  called "Generate Code" you will your request was written with more languages choose swift and find what in headers dictionary

Comment: Thanks for "Generate Code part".. I never looked up there, but sorry if I am being dense I still got no response and header Dictionary looks like this

let headers = [
  "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
  "key": "value",
  "cache-control": "no-cache",
  "postman-token": "xxxxxx3x-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
]

Comment: Ok try change "content-type" key to "accept" key and hope this to help you :)